# Convert Class[_] to universe.Type/Symbol

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm trying to list all classes from a package and extract some metadata information through the new reflection api(2.10).

I may be wrong, but seems that there is no support to list classes from a package on the scala api.

I'm using a [java library](http://code.google.com/p/reflections), but it returns only the `Class<?>`

It is possible to convert a `Class[_]` to `universe.Type` or `universe.Symbol`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shoud use mirrors of `scala.reflect.runtime.universe` ([JavaUniverse](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse))

Suppose you have a runtime class:

```
val cls: Class[_] = someObject.getClass
```

You should get `runtimeMmirror` ([JavaMirror](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.JavaMirrors%24JavaMirror)) for your classloader and call its `classSymbol` method, which converts runtime class to ClassSymbol for this universe:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime._

val typ: universe.ClassSymbol = universe.runtimeMirror(cls.getClassLoader).classSymbol(cls)
```